# Safe Encrypt/Decrypt Algo that works in URLS (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encryption

I am using the encryptor gem from https://github.com/shuber/encryptor and need to be able to have a url safe values. Is there an algo. that support this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to base64 encode the encryption result.

Comment: Keep in mind that base64-encoding a result does not provide any security at all. See http://www.blesta.com/2009/07/26/encoding-vs-encryption/.

Comment: I am base64 encoding an encryption result, so I think I am ok.

Comment: I think base64 can include forward slashes, beware

Comment: for URL purposes better to use `urlsafe_encode64` and `urlsafe_decode64`